# replace increasing digits of an array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have generated a random binary number in the form of an array of char with a fixed length

```
    public char[] biNum(int length) {

        char[] biStr = new char[length];
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            biStr[i] = (char)r.nextInt(1);
        }
        return biStr;
    }
```

how do I get multiple such arrays with increment number of '*' at random positions in it?
example: if the length is 8, then

```
100*10*1 has 2 '*'
10*01*** has 4 '*'
0******1 has 6 '*'
```

I'm not trying to get a 2 dimension array here. But if that was easier then I am ok with that too

```
    for (i = 2; i < length; i+2){
        biNum(20);
        //some method that adds i '*' in biStr
        System.out.println(biStr);
    }
```

what I was thinking was, in the for loop add another loop

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    generate j random numbers
    for every random number
        biStr[random number] = '*'
```

but then I need to make sure there's no duplicate random number. I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: One way might be to [shuffle an array of 0 to 19](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20011599/1270789) then pick the first 2 or 4 or six, etc from the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the fastest way to generate such, but, one of the ways to implement it.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class BitCount {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                char[] c = new char[20];
                Random rand = new Random();
                int limit = 8;
                int i = 0;
                for ( i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++ ) {
                        c[i] = '*';
                }
                for ( i = limit ; i < 20 ; i++ ) {
                        int r = rand.nextInt(2);
                        c[i] = (char)((int)'0' + r);
                }
                for ( i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) {
                        int i_from = rand.nextInt(20);
                        int i_to = rand.nextInt(20);
                        if ( i_from != i_to ) {
                                char cz = c[i_to];
                                c[i_to] = c[i_from];
                                c[i_from] = cz;
                        }
                }
                System.out.println(new String(c));
        }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approch, but I'd use the [perfect shuffle algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011599/java-perfect-shuffle-using-arrays) at the end instead.